# using trickle to slow down browser

Tags: http, rate-limiting

according to trickle's man page, http://linux.die.net/man/1/trickle i can limit the download speed of a process, e.g.

`trickle -u 10 -d 20 ncftp`
to Launch ncftp(1) limiting its upload capacity to 10 KB/s, and download capacity at 20 KB/s.

how would I go about limiting `google-chrome` or `firefox` with `trickle`?

Edit:
For those of you asking why I asked such an obvious question, I tried

`trickle -u 10 -d 20 firefox`

and I'm getting an error

`trickle: Could not reach trickled, working independently: No such file or directory`

firefox opens right after, but is definitely not rate limited...

Comment: The question belongs on Stackoverflow. It's recursive and never ends.

Comment: In all seriousness, I don't get it. You're answering yourself in the question.

Comment: I tried running `ubuntuone-syncdaemon` through trickle; using the daemon, I get rate limiting, without it, I don't. I wonder if some forking activity in the process leads to this problem ... either way it does seem to be a bug, so I'm not sure why the answer below got accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the confusion stems from your comprehension of the man page. `ncftp` is the name of the process being limited, so to limit firefox you would do:

```
trickle -u 10 -d 20 firefox
```

Answer (score 7):

The "error" you're getting is more of a warning/notice than an error. `trickle` can be run standalone or as a client of `trickled`. It always looks for the default socket of the daemon and if not found it prints that message. You can safely ignore it.

And about rate limiting `Firefox`, I'm pretty sure it has to do with the forking of the process, as [David Fraser](https://serverfault.com/users/18714/david-fraser) mentioned. You can also see a warning about it in [Arch's Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Trickle), where it says:

> **Warning**: Trickle can only limit traffic of programs that do not fork, so shaping a FTP server's traffic won't really work that way!

In my own experience, I've tried to limit [`aws-cli`](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) tool for S3 upload unsuccessfully, but have been able to limit [`s3cmd`](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) instead. Both tools are written in python, but `aws-cli` are many different programs bundled through a main one while `s3cmd` is a single program. I'm guessing the same issue with forking is happening there.

So my short answer is: I don't think you can rate limit those browsers using `trickle`.